# Parsing a web page using Javascript (ajax and jquery involved)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to parse an ajax requested page for the word "function" and store the last matched character in an array. The only errors JSLint is returning are

> unexpected ('space')

and

> Combine this statement with the previous 'var' statement,

neither of which I believe should effect whether or not the code is executed. Any help is appreciated.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";


    //retrieve page
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",      "https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/init.27d18bf5a2b7d3e5fbcdbb86f85e7a534b11f06b.js", true);  
    xhr.responseType = "text";
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = function () {

        //set variables to be compared
        var page = xhr.responseText;
        var word = "function";

        //page and word locations
        var i = 0;
        var n = 0;
        var page_loc = page[i];            
        var word_loc = word[n];

        //matched result storage
        var chain = [""];

        // compare
        while (n < word.length - 1) {
            if (page_loc === word_loc) {
                n = n + 1;
                i = i + 1;
                console.log(i);
            } else {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }

        //place matched result
        chain.push(page_loc);
        console.log(chain);
    };
});
```

Comment: _page for the word "function" and store the last matched character in an array_ what does the last matched character mean? Would you like just to check if the "function" exists withing given page and return its last character?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear I just meant the last character in the string im searching for, so in this case the "n" in "function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So regarding your comment and question.

You don't need to iterate over that string, if you only want to check whether a given string is present in a response, you can use a built-in function [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or in newer browsers [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

So the code would look as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  "use strict";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/init.27d18bf5a2b7d3e5fbcdbb86f85e7a534b11f06b.js", true);  
  xhr.responseType = "text";
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var page = xhr.responseText;
    var word = "function";
    if (page.indexOf(word) !== -1)
      console.log([word[word.length-1]]);
  };
  xhr.send();
});
```

Comment: "First of all, you must add the listener before send() is fired," — Not true. Since JavaScript is single threaded, there is no way the event handler can be searched for before the function that is both assigning it and calling send() is finished.

Comment: Good to know, removed!